# Login should be in center of the page

Tags: php, codeigniter

In the below code i have placed the controller.the actual result is ligin is in center position but it is in the bottom.My expected result is login should come in center of the page.pls help me to do this.
Controller:

```
<html>
<head>

 </head>
<title>login_form</title>
<BODY onLoad="noBack();" onpageshow="if (event.persisted) noBack();" onUnload=""><div class="container">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="span4 logo">
                   <img src="<?php echo base_url('img/logosl.png'); ?>"  style="margin-bottom:7px; margin-top:7px;"/>
             </div>

<center ><div id="login_form" >

    <h1>Login!</h1>



    <form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/login/validate_credentials" method="post" >
    <input type="text"  name="username" required placeholder="username"  style="height: 25px;" value=""  />
    <input type="text"  name="password" required placeholder="password"  style="height: 25px;" value=""  />
    <input type="text"  name="college_name" required placeholder="college_name"  style="height: 25px;" value=""  />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"  class="btn-success btn" />

    <a href="login/signup">Create Account</a>
    </form>


</div></center><!-- end login_form-->


<?php $this->load->view('includes/header'); ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style1.css"  />




<?php $this->load->view('includes/footer'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
body {
    background:#FFFFFF;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: arial;
}
#login_form {
    width: 300px;
    background: #f0f0f0 url(../img/login_bg.jpg) repeat-x 0 0;
    border: 1px solid white;
    margin: 250px auto 0;
    padding: 1em;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5 {
    margin-top: 0;
    font-family: arial black, arial;
    text-align: center;
}

input[type=text], input[type=password] {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    width: 280px;
    border: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
    padding: 1em;
}

input[type=submit], form a {
    border: none;
    margin-right: 1em;
    padding: 6px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    background: #348075;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white;

}

input[type=submit]:hover, form a:hover {
    background: #287368;
    cursor: pointer;
}




/* Validation error messages */

.error {
    color: #393939;
    font-size: 15px;
}

fieldset {
    width: 300px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    display: block;
}

/* FOR FUN */

h1 {
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 white;
}

/* Not necessary. Just the "tutorial created by" stuff at the bottom */

#tutInfo {
    background: #e3e3e3;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: .7em .7em .7em 2em;
}
```

Comment: can you show us your css? maybe you have an float right/left

Comment: Wow. Do I actually see a HTML center tag? lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing < / div>

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="span4 logo">
               <img src="<?php echo base_url('img/logosl.png'); ?>"  style="margin-bottom:7px; margin-top:7px;"/>
         </div>
**</div>**
```

Comment: it is not working login is in center but it is in bottom of the page .the page get scroll to click login

Comment: Yes, that's because you are setting **margin: 250px auto 0;**  
try reducing it?
    margin: 50px auto 0;

Comment: #login_form {
    width: 300px;
    background: #f0f0f0 url(../img/login_bg.jpg) repeat-x 0 0;
    border: 1px solid white;
    margin: _50px_ auto 0;
    padding: 1em;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
}